# Template Specialization pointer to pointer and array passing template deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have the following code I was writing to test template specialization. Is there a way to have the pointer decay to the type so that I can use template parameter deduction to get my M and N so I can have the rows and cols of the two dimensional array? I know I can vector of vector for a 2d array, but this is an exercise in template specialization. The following code works as is, but see if you uncomment the following and comment out the current T** constructor it doesn't work. As a result the constructor currently hard codes the number of rows to be used for deleting the data_ member, this is not ideal and ideally I would get this parameter from the template deduction. I was wondering if there is a way to make this work in the following code shown below.

```
        //doesn't like this constructor
    //  template <unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
    //  Data ( T (&d)[M][N]  ): data_(d), rows_(M), cols_(N) {};

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Data
{
  public:
  Data ( const T& d ): data_(d) {};
  Data ( T&& d ): data_(std::move(d)) {};

  std::string getType() { return "Plain Data Type"; }

  private: 
  T  data_;
};


template <typename T>
class Data<T**>
{
  public:

    //doesn't like this constructor
//  template <unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
//  Data ( T (&d)[M][N]  ): data_(d), rows_(M), cols_(N) {};
  Data ( T** d ): data_(d), rows_(25) {};
  ~Data() { 

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)    
    {
      delete [] data_[i];
    }
    delete [] data_;
  }

  std::string getType() { return "Pointer to Pointer Data Type"; }

  private:
  T**  data_;
  unsigned int rows_;
  unsigned int cols_;
};


template <typename T>
class Data<T*>
{
  public:
  Data ( T* d ): data_(d) {};
  ~Data() { delete data_; }

  std::string getType() { return "Pointer Data Type"; }

  private:
  T*  data_;
};


int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float f(9.65);
  Data<int> d1(f);
  std::cout << d1.getType() << std::endl;

  int *i = new int(5);
  Data<int*> d2(i);
  std::cout << d2.getType() << std::endl;

  int **j = new int*[25];
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 25; ++i)
    j[i] = new int[50];

  Data<int**> d3(j);
  std::cout << d3.getType() << std::endl;
}


output:
Plain Data Type
Pointer Data Type
Pointer to Pointer Data Type
```

Comment: Judging by your comments about the invalid constructor, if you think `T**` and `T[n][m]` are equivalent, you're wrong. They're not.

Comment: A 2D array is not a pointer to a pointer and does not decay into one.

Comment: I see ... but this happens with a one dimensional array correct?

Comment: can I make a template specialization for a 2D array?

Comment: shouldn't T **d  and T *d[] be the same in this case as an argument to the constructor? if I wanted to get the bounds how would I do this?  I know with a single array I can use template <unsigned int N> foo (T (&d)[N])

Comment: You can do the same with a 2-dimension array (which, again, is *not* the same as `T**`). In fact, with a variadic solution if you were really set on it, you can do it for an arbitrary dimension limit.

Comment: point taken and upvoted on the T** and T[N][M] not being the same. Yes, they don't teach this in school...

Comment: Again... `T**` is *not a dimensioned array*. It is a pointer-to-pointer. It has no intrinsic size characteristic like a formal array. It is as different to a dimensioned formal array as `T*` is to `T[N]`. *They're different*. One is a pointer to `T`, the other is an array of T of size N. Yes, the array has an address which is the "value" when used as a "pointer value" (such as a parameter), but they're *not* the same.

Comment: I think my confusion revolved around the fact that I was using the array version of operator new `int **j = new int*[25];` So I thought I could get the 25 bound using template deduction for `T* d[]` but this doesn't seem to be the case. I am just passing the 25 in the constructor for T** specialization now so it knows how many it has to clean up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T**` and `T[n][m]` are not equivalent (and I curse the collegiate professors that refuse to teach this). One is  a pointer-to-pointer, the other is an array of `T[m]` of size `n`.

You can specialize your 2D array type like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class Data<T[N][M]>
{
public:
    Data(const T(&ar)[N][M])
    {
        for (size_t i=0;i<N;++i)
            std::copy(std::begin(ar[i]), std::end(ar[i]), std::begin(data[i]));
    }

    std::string getType() { return "2D-Fixed Array Data Type"; }

private:
    T data[N][M];
};
```

And one way to use it is like this:

```
float fdat[10][20];
Data<decltype(fdat)> d4(fdat);
std::cout << d4.getType() << std::endl;
```

**Output**

2D-Fixed Array Data Type

Comment: When you say the ohter is an array to T[m] should this be T[n*m]?

Comment: @bjackfly No. The formal underlying type of the array is `T[m]`. As in, `T[n][m]` is an array of size `n` of `T[m]`. It is precisely the same concept and vernacular used for single dimensions. I.e. `T[n]` is an array of size `n` of `T`.